# Trigger Bluetooth with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

I have a client who has a few bluetooth devices connected to an iPad. On that iPad I will be creating a website designed for the iPad (the iPad will be in a kiosk setup).

Is it possible using only javascript to trigger a specific device via bluetooth (assuming you know the bluetooth ID or address)? For instance there will be bluetooth controlled lighting, when the end user visit a specific page a specific light will be triggered via bluetooth.

Is this possible? If so, please provide some so resources that I may learn how to do this.

Note: The website is not a dedicated iPad app, just a standard HTML, CSS, and JS website. Also my site runs on a hosted CMS, thus *no* server side code can be used. I will be using jQuery 1.8.3 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Impossible, you can't do this. When was the last time you wanted random Internet sites to hijack your hardware?

Comment: @meagar - You wouldn't. My thought was if I know the specific bluetooth ID or address (which would be practically impossible to randomly guess) you could write code that would say `If you = this bluetooth address turn on else do nothing`. That is the idea at least, though I do not fully know how bluetooth fully, but regardless of my concept evidently you cannot do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It's not possible to access native iPad functions through javascript....
Wider answer: It's not possible to access hardware through Javascript

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. You don't learn if you don't ask. Work just grew easier. YEAH!